# Objective-C: If I return a C++ object in a function in ARC, will it create a copy and do I have to manually release that copy?

Tags: c++, objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c++

I am trying to pass a reference to a C++ Object in Objective-C, so I can access that object from another class, specifically:

```
// ClassA
-(b2World *)getWorld{
    return world;
}
```

In another class I would either assign the returned object to an ivar

```
// ClassB
-(void)initClassB{
    world_ = [ClassA getWorld];
}
```

or directly access a method of the returned object

```
// Classb
-(void)doSomething{
    [[ClassA getWorld] doSomething];
}
```

Is it correct that in both cases the c++ object (b2World) is copied and that I have to manually release the copied object in an ARC environment? If so, what is the best practice to pass c++ objects in ARC (the ownership of the passed object should not be transferred, e.g. it should be a weak reference)?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You have to tell ARC that it's to keep its bleeping fingers off that pointer!  (I've never done this, so I don't know the precise `_whatever` modifier to use.)

Comment: @HotLicks for a properly defined C++ class that isn't the case. ARC is much smarter than that, and only retains pointers of types with the `__attribute__((NSObject))` declaration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not returning an object. You're returning a pointer. There is no copying going on anywhere.

Also, your third code sample will never work, because you said `b2World` is a C++ object, meaning it can't possibly respond to obj-c messages.

Also, ARC doesn't affect the semantics of C++ (except when you embed obj-c objects as member variables of C++ objects).